# How to match all except last one

Tags: regex, bash

I have a large list of files, like this:

```
/tmp/a/b/a
/var/files/z
/tmp/o
.
.
.
```

I need to match, in every line, all the directories but not the file name.
How can I do it with bash?

Comment: What do you mean "match"? What are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're assuming every path ends with a file, then you can just use [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname).

```
dirname /var/files/z
/var/files
```

If you have a mixture of files and directories, you can use bash's `-d` and `-f` [file test operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) to check before you run `dirname`.

Answer (score 2):

Bash:

```
path="$(pwd)"
echo "$path"
echo "${path%/*}"
```